# Visual Studio - Configuration Manager

Tags: visual-studio, configuration-management

By default when creating a new solution, VS 2015 gives you two solution configurations: Debug and Release. I want to know if it is okay to remove these two configurations. I want to create three: Development, Testing and Production to match the nomenclature of my organization and do not want to have confusion with Debug and Release.

So any reason I should NOT remove these two?

Comment: You can rename DEBUG to Development and Release to Production while you could create Testing copying one of the twos

Comment: That could work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't delete the Debug and Release configurations.
Configurations are not just a name. The Debug configuration for example defines a preprocessor variable called DEBUG  that you can use to add or skip blocks of code with the preprocessor statement `#if`.
The Release configuration instead contains settings used by the compiler to produce optimized code.

However you can rename DEBUG to Development and Release to Production while you could create Testing copying one of the twos and adding your own settings (like a preprocessor variable called TEST for example)

To rename a configuration use the menu `Configuration Manager` inside the `Build` menu.
Then in the Active Solutions Configuration combobox choose `<Edit>`
The following form contains the button that allows you to rename the configurations but preserve the orignal settings

To create a new configuration use the same menu but choose `<New>` instead of `<Edit>`

This article on MSDN seems pretty interesting
[Understanding Build Configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx)

Comment: Agree with your answer, however would it not be safer to simply copy the Debug and Release and rename each copied configuration accordingly. I worry there would be tools and such which may expect Debug/Release names for the configuration when interacting with VS? Just a thought.